# Multiple environments on one server

Tags: django, reactjs, server, mern

What is the best practice or tutorial to set up a droplet to showcase my React/Express and Django fullstack projects on a single server?

I've found NGINX server blocks, but not sure if I'm going in the right direction.

I want users to go to a React site that will have links to several other React or Django projects running on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it all out.

You can use all of the regular server block documentation if you have another domain name or subdomain name you want to point to the server. That documentation can be found at [Nginx Documentation on Server Blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) and [Digital Ocean post on server blocks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)

If you want to make multiple server blocks within subdirectories of the root server you can use location as seen here in the Nginx documentation: [ServerFault question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/218818/nginx-projects-in-subfolders)